# How do I proceed building a nearby photography attractions app?

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I'm new to app development, and basically programming. I plan to build an app that lists out nearby attractions for photographers, like natural attractions, architecture, street photography locations, etc. along with suggestions from other users about what time of day to go, reviews, etc. I plan to learn learn everything on the go, instead of learning first and then building the app. So, how do I start? What technologies, APIs and languages should I get my hands on to build the said app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use

> **Google Places API**

using that you have to filter out what all places of interests you want to show, [here](https://developers.google.com/places/) are the details of the api, that's the one you need to get started it's there for web, Android, ios